# It is slow when using the column in mysql select in another select

Tags: mysql

in the code below, I get the query about how many products there are in the categories under an ad category.

However, when I use the following where words, the query takes 40 seconds, if not, it gives results in 2 seconds.

```
product_categories.category_id LIKE CONCAT (cat_code, '%')

LENGTH (cat_code) <LENGTH (product_categories.category_id)
```

The number of data is 40 000.

I need to use this query because I can select the categories under the category "103203" that I have specified.

I think this slowness occurs when I use the cat_code column.

```
  SELECT
    categories.CODE AS cat_code,
    categories.NAME,
    (
    SELECT
        COUNT( * ) 
    FROM
        ads
        JOIN products ON ads.product_id = products.id
        JOIN product_categories ON ads.product_id = product_categories.product_id
        JOIN b2b_users ON b2b_users.id = ads.uid
        JOIN categories ON product_categories.category_id = categories.CODE 
    WHERE
        b2b_users.ads_status = '1' 
        AND ads.STATUS = '1' 
        AND product_categories.category_id LIKE CONCAT( cat_code, '%' )
        AND product_categories.category_id != 103203 
        AND ads.stock > '0' 
        AND ads.banned = '0' 
    ) AS total,
    (
    SELECT
        COUNT( * ) 
    FROM
        ads
        JOIN products ON ads.product_id = products.id
        JOIN product_categories ON ads.product_id = product_categories.product_id
        JOIN b2b_users ON b2b_users.id = ads.uid
        JOIN categories ON product_categories.category_id = categories.CODE 
    WHERE
        b2b_users.ads_status = '1' 
        AND ads.STATUS = '1' 
        AND product_categories.category_id LIKE CONCAT( cat_code, '%' ) 
        AND product_categories.category_id != 103203 
        AND ads.stock > '0' 
        AND ads.banned = '0' 
        AND LENGTH( cat_code )< LENGTH( product_categories.category_id )
        LIMIT 1 
    ) AS subcattotal 
FROM
    categories 
WHERE
    catid = 103203 
ORDER BY
    categories.NAME ASC
```

Comment: What is the datatype of `category_id`? It looks like it's a number, but testing it with `LIKE` requires converting it to a string. That prevents use of the index, so it has to perform a full scan.

Comment: Why are you using `LIKE` to match numbers?

Comment: If you want to match all the categories IDs beginning with `103`, you should use `category_id BETWEEN 103000 and 103999`. This will use the index.

Comment: If your category IDs are structured, it would probably be better to split it into two columns: one for the code, another for the sub-ID.

Comment: I overlooked the data type of category_id is varchar. I converted it to integer and it went from 40 seconds to 18 seconds. but I think I need to speed it up a little bit, what is your advice?

Comment: top category number, 103203. Categories starting with 103203 that I need. Such as 103203001,103203002 ...

Comment: Is there an index on `product_id`? If there is, LIKE should be able to use it.

Comment: Use `EXPLAIN` to see what indexes are being used.